# MediaWiki - Cannot edit Main Page

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I have recently restored two wikis from a backup after a harddisk failure. The wikis make use of a single MySQL database, each of them using prefixed tables. One of the wikis is running just fine after the restore; the other one is not.

The issue is that all of the content on the malfunctioning wiki's main page is gone; the page just displays the sample text "There is currently no text in this page. You can search ..." Even worse, I cannot edit the wiki's main page: clicking the edit button when registered brings up the message "No such section --- You tried to edit a section that does not exist. Since there is no section , there is no place to save your edit."

What's also confusing is that all of the other pages seem to be fine; I can search for pages, and clicking on "Random page" does what it's supposed to do. I can also edit all other pages except for the main page.

Has anyone come across anything remotely similar?

I am pretty sure it has to be an error within the database. If I export an XML dump of all the pages, the main page is not among the pages in the XML. However, the page table contains an entry for the main page. How can I test the validity of that entry?

Comment: Page text is in the `text` table )or the `archive` table if it was deleted). If you find it there, you can just delete and recreate the page. If you don't find it there, chances are it is lost.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is really present in the database as you say (which requires not only `page` table but also `text` table, as Tgr said), but is not accessible, the most likely reason would be an incorrect namespace. Does the page title contain a colon?

Try running `php maintenance/namespaceDupes.php --fix`.